# Apply indexes on left outer join table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have below kind of query which uses left outer join but my indexes are not working, when I am doing Explain Query:

```
SELECT p.ProductName,p.ProductDesc, p.ProductSize, p.ProductPrice, c.CategoryName
FROM Product p
Left Outer Join Category c ON p.Category_id = c.CategoryID
WHERE (:product_id is null or p.ProductId in (
  SELECT TRIM(regex_substr(:product_id,'[^,]+',1,level) as id)
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE TRIM(regex_substr(:product_id,'[^,]+',1,level)) is not null
  CONNECT TRIM(regex_substr(:product_id,'[^,]+',1,level) as id) is not null
))
```

I put indexes on CategoryId in table Category and Product and productId in Product, But explain query not showing any indexes at all rather all table are full scan. Kindly suggest.

It was performing issues for which I added indexes on category Id since that was causing full table scan.

EDIT:
Data Stats: Product table has half million records and category has approx. some 20k records. And not sure why but this query is taking approx 13 min to extract full data to csv. I am using SQL developer to extract data.

Comment: The DBMS considers using an index as disadvantageous here. It can happen that it will have to join all or very many rows from the tables. It plays save and prefers full table scans (and probably hash joins) over using indexes, so as to have a reliable, stable execution plan. I'd do just the same. You might be able to force using an index with an appropriate hint, but I think you shouldn't. Stick with the execution plan the DBMS has found; it probably knows better than you how to best access the data.

Comment: Your `JOIN` condition has no `ON` condition and, so, the query is syntactically invalid.

Comment: I have corrected query

Comment: I see from your edit that you are exporting the data to CSV. It may well be that the job in the DBMS is not what is taking that much time, but rather getting the rows from the database server to your PC and writing them to a file on your disk. How much time does it take to `select count(*)` instead?

Comment: Performance issues has nothing to do with indexes in this case. To measure DBMS performance you should exclude everything external, so the cleanest  comparison of runtime of one (large result set) query with another would be CTAS. But it seems that the bottleneck is in CSV serialization (my experience shows that `spool` dramatically reduces throughput compared to CTAS).

Answer (score 1):

A table named "`Category`" sounds like it has very few rows and when joined to the "`Product`" table probably nearly all its rows will be needed.

That being the case, Oracle will naturally choose a full table scan and hash join rather than use an index, and that decision would be a correct one. Don't assume that indexes should be used just because they are present. Gather stats on both tables and if it still wants to avoid the index, let it alone, unless there's a felt performance problem you're experiencing.

I do *not* recommend this, but if you *had* to force it to use the index against it's better judgment, you can either flip it to the RBO (rule-based optimizer) using the `/*+ rule */` hint, or you can specify the index with the `/*+ INDEX(c) */` hint. But again, I reiterate, in all likelihood you don't want it using an index on such a table for such a query as this.

Comment: Just to confirm Product table has half million records and category has approx some 20k records. This query is taking approx 13 min to execute

Comment: I have doubt if index work with left outer join?

Comment: Still, with half million product records joining to 20k category records, you don't want to use an index. Oracle is correct about doing a hash join + full scan on the category table. Indexes are for when you need a tiny, tiny percent of the target table (in this case, category).

Comment: Outer vs inner join makes no difference. It can use an index in either case, but it can also decide not to. Oracle's CBO (cost-based optimizer) is intelligent, it doesn't blindly following a static path every time.

Comment: What could be wrong with this query causing 13 min to extract half million records.

Comment: 13 min is Extraction time from start of first record till all half million downloaded to csv at my local.

Comment: SQL Developer on your local machine writing to a CSV is not going to be very fast. Try selecting straight from the product table without any filters or joins and see how long a half million records takes to write to a CSV. If it's similar, you'll know that it's simply network, SQL Developer processing, and file writing on your local client, not database time.

Comment: And if you want to know for sure, consult gv$active_session_history for your sqlid to see how many CPU and non-idle waits seconds were recorded for your execution.